# Screen capturing excluding some window in linux

Tags: linux, screen-capture

I'm trying to get screenshots every N milliseconds and I want not to show my own program widgets in this screenshot. User mustn't know any information from this program.
There is exist Magnification API for Windows to do such thing and this API works.

Is there any C++/C library for Linux?

Comment: Look for pipewire, but you can't generally have a "User mustn't know any information from this program." This really sound shady

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I meant user will not be able to see windows of my program on screenshots, though they can be still active on desktop.
Could you show the part of code where this functionality is implemented, please? I took a look at pipewire but didn't find anything.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. But I know pipewire is the latest API for screen and sound capture on linux.